# Fixed header on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a functionality where the header gets fixed before the website header. Once it reaches that certain point I set it as `position:fixed` . But for some reason in some scenario, it jitters back to `postion:relative`

It does not stick to the top as expected for some reason, What could be the problem?

```
var stickyHeaderTop = $('.tab1').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if( ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop-60) && (width>1200) ) {
        console.log('im here');
        $('.tab1').css({position: 'fixed', top: '60px', width: left,zIndex:'999'});
        $('.tab2').css({position: 'fixed', top: '60px', width: right});
        $('.tab3').css({position: 'fixed', top: '60px', width: thirdCol,background: '#ffffff',zIndex:'99999'});
    } else {
        console.log('nooo,, i cant stick im here');
        $('.tab1').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
        $('.tab2').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
        $('.tab3').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
    }
});
```

When this block gets executed, only once the log `im here` gets printed rest of the times the `nooo,, i cant stick im here` gets printed.

Comment: I guess, if condition is getting false in all subsequent calls. Log the width and $(window).scrollTop(), stickyHeaderTop in console you will get to know the answer to your questoin

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ?? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewzrmW?editors=1000

Comment: can you post your all code here?it would be more helpfull

Comment: @Rehan I would suggest you to use bootstrap for this, check out this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed&stacked=h

Comment: The problem is once the code is executed the whole window scrolls up few px automatically

Comment: why not use much performant native solution, `position: sticky;`